# How to grant subscription access to an azure registered application?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to set up octopus to deploy resources to azure.

Under azure active directory I've added a new app registration, and have generated a key and hooked up octopus with the correct Application ID,  Tenant ID and key

The organisation has multiple azure subscriptions corresponding to the environments, so I've noticed if I use the Subscription ID of my "Visual Studio Professional MSDN" subscription it works and creates the resources, however if I try to use any of the other organisation Subscription IDs I get the following error:

> Login-AzureRmAccount : The provided account c0b2.......76a6 does not
>   have access to subscription ID "f06.......2aa3". Please try logging in
>   with different  credentials or a different subscription ID.

I have looked through all the settings of the Application Registration and granted it every "Windows Azure Active Directory" permission available, but still no luck.

How do I go about granting permissions to this Application Registration so that it can access the relevant subscriptions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to give the app a role on the subscription/resource group/resource you want it to be able to access.

So for example, you can go to the Access Control (IAM) tab of the subscription, and give the app the Contributor role, which allows the app to read and modify anything in the subscription.
You can also give a more limited role if desired.
Roles can also be applied at a lower scope, like a resource group.

More info in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal

Comment: Thank you! I saw that, but dismissed that as I thought this was for users only, but just noticed applications appear too.